# force rpy2 in conda environment to use the R outside of the conda environment

Tags: python, r, conda, rpy2

I started using conda environments. I know that I can open and use R jupiter notebook, but my preferred workflow is to use R within a python notebook, when necessary, with rpy2 and push/pull data between the two languages

```
%R push data
%R run something
%R pull output
```

however now when I run rpy2 in a conda environment, it searches for all packages in the R folder within the conda environment. I would like to use the packages installed in my home directory or those from the machine I work on, without the need to reinstall everything for each conda environment. Is that possible?

Comment: did you figured out how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to tell R about package directories (http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/libPaths.html).

Try setting the environment variable R_LIBS or R_LIBS_USER (before `%load_ext rpy2.ipython` in the notebook).

Comment: this is a hack that will not always work (the R process will still dynamically load shared libraries [=\= R packages] from the conda environment)